# Switched carriers after ordering iPhone 11

Tags: cellular-carriers, setup

I ordered the iPhone 11 with Verizon on the day it came out, and a few days later my family switched from Verizon to T-Mobile. When I'm setting up my phone, it's still trying to activate with Verizon, even when I switch the SIM out for my T-Mobile SIM. How do I resolve this problem?

Edit: I forgot to that this was ordered as part of the iPhone Upgrade Program with Apple, which says that the phone should be unlocked.

Comment: Speak to the original carrier… then probably the 2nd carrier. The first will still 'own the deal' if you bought it from them. If you bought it unlocked from Apple, it will be swappable.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your iPhone is unlocked from Verizon. Make sure that they remove your IMEI number from the account. Verizon can unlock the device, but if you haven't paid it off they wont.

Comment: I missed an important detail in my original question, see the edit.

Comment: @erdekhayser try erasing the device and then re-activating it with your current SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

Your Verizon supplied phone is subject to a Verizon plan and SIM card. It's useless on a T-Mobile plan and SIM card, and you'll probably find that you're required to keep paying for your Verizon plan as ordering the phone will have extended that plan for several years.

Verizon may offer you to pay the entire retail price of the phone in exchange for unlocking it, or allow you to return the phone to them at a penalty restocking fee.

Comment: I missed an important detail in my original question, see the edit.